# A counter-example to Dini's Theorem (after removing a hypothesis)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Recall Dini's Theorem:

> Let $K$ be a compact metric space. Let $f: K\to\mathbb{R}$ be a
>   continuous function and  $f_{n}: K\to\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be
>   a sequence of continuous functions. If  $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
>   converges to $f$ and if $f_{n}(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x\in K$ and
>   all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges
>   uniformly to $f$.

It is known that the hypotheses:

- $K$ is compact
- $f$ is continuous
- $f_{n}(x)$ decreases as $n$ increases

are necessary. See this [document.](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/dini.pdf)

Me and my friend are looking for an example where:

- $K$ is compact
- $f$ is continuous
- $f_{n}(x)$ decreases as $n$ increases
- $f_{n}$ are not continuous
- $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise, but $f_{n}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$

We have been thinking for 2 hours, but to no avail!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/dinis-theorem-and-tests-for-uniform-convergence/82776#82776).

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thanks David! Your answer in that thread is very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified version of David Mitra's answer from this [thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/dinis-theorem-and-tests-for-uniform-convergence/82776#82776)

$$ f_n(x)=\begin{cases}-1 & 0\le x\le 1-{1\over n}\cr 0&1-{1\over n}< x<1\\-1\;&x=1\end{cases} $$

answers the question. The limit function is the constant function $f=-1$.