# Example for a sequence of continuous functions which converge to a continuous function pointwise but not uniformly on a compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

My actual aim is to verify that each of the conditions in Dini's theorem is essential or not.Theorem says that  A sequence {$f_{n}$} of continuous functions defined on a **compact** set $E$  converges to $f$ point wise  satisfying the following properties :
$f_{n}$ is monotonic 
and $f$ is continuous. 
Then {$f_{n}$} converges to $f$ uniformly.

So there are three hypothesis are used in theorem **compactness of $E$**,**continuity of $f$** and **monotonicity of $f_{n}$**.
First one is essential because $f_{n}= \frac{1}{1+nx}$ defined on open interval $(0,1)$ converge to $o$ point wise but not uniformly.Second condition cannot be omitted since $f_{n}=x^{n}$ defined on $[0,1]$ converges to a discontinuous function.

Left out one is monotonicity.For that I need to construct a sequence of functions which are continuous, non-monotonic,and converges point wise to a continuous function.But convergence should not be uniform.

I could not get such a sequence.

Comment: There was a mistake in my question sorry..I need a sequence of continuous functions on a compact set which converges point wise to a continuous function.But the sequence should not be monotonic Then convergence should not be uniform.So I am editing my question.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861746/a-counter-example-to-dinis-theorem-after-removing-a-hypothesis#861762

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n$ be a big "spike" with support in $[0, 2/n]$. To be precise:

For $n \geq 2$, let $f_n$ be the unique piecewise linear function on $[0,1]$ such that:

(a) $f_n = 0$ on $[2/n, 1]$,

(b) $f_n$ is linear on $[0,1/n]$ and $[1/n, 2/n]$,

(c) $f_n(0) = f_n(2/n) = 0$, and

(d) $f_n(1/n) = n$.

The $f_n$ converge to zero, but certainly not uniformly.

Comment: Will it be monotonic ?

Comment: @Madhu: No, it isn't monotonic.  (For one thing, if it were it would contradict Dini's theorem!)  But it is easy to see this if you draw pictures of the functions $f_n$; for a fixed number $x_0$ that is close to 0 you will see $f_n(x_0)$ increase and then decrease as $n$ grows.

Comment: yes..Earlier there was a mistake in my question I need a non monotonic function Now I have edited the question.I will give one example based on your answer..(surely not my invention)

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on hints given by Nate Eldredge. But this one I obtained from one more book.

$f_{n}(x)=n^{2}x$  if   $ 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} $,

= $-n^{2}x+2n$   if $ \frac{1}{n} <x< \frac{2}{n}$

=$0$ if $\frac{2}{n} \leq x \leq 1$ .

Here we have to start with $n=2$.

Graph of this function will look like triangle with changing base.