# Why does the sequence of functions have to be increasing/decreasing in Dini's theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I think as long as a sequence of continuous functions converges pointwise to a continuous function on a closed interval, the convergence would be uniform.

Can someone tell me why it's wrong?

Comment: If you can puzzle this out for yourself, it will be a nice accomplishment that sticks in your memory.

Comment: Can you prove what you state, That is: if $S_n(x) \rightarrow S(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and all the $S_n$ are continuous then $sup_{x \in [a,b]}|S_n(x) - S(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $n$ big enough and $n+1, n+2 \dots$

Comment: If you read and understand the details of the proof then you will see why it is needed in the proof of Dini's Theorem.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/82766/

Answer (score 2):

A typical counterexample is $f_n(x) = \max(1-|nx-1|,0)$, which is a confusing way to say: thin triangles of constant height.

[image]