# point-wise convergent sequence of continuous functions is equicontinuous at x?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Say that $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of point-wise continuous function on $[a,b]$. Suppose that the sequence to $f$. Let $x \in [a,b]$. Is it true that $f_{n}(x)$ are equicontinuous at $x$ if $n>N$ for some sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Assuming that $f_n$ just converges to $f$ pointwise then certainly not - there are simple examples where $f$ is not even continuous at $x$, hence the sequence cannot be equicontinuous. Of course if $f_n\to f$ uniformly then yes.

Comment: Right, but there are plenty of sequences of continuous functions that converge to a discontinious one. My question is: if they are continuous, are they eventually equicontinuous?

Comment: ??? You mean to be including the condition that $f$ is also continuous? You didn't say so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example is taken from
[Dini's Theorem and tests for uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/dinis-theorem-and-tests-for-uniform-convergence/82776#82776):

> Take $K=[0,1]$ and let $f_n(x)$ be the function whose graph consists of the straight line segment from $(0,0)$ to $({1\over2n},1)$, the straight line segment from $({1\over2n},1)$ to $({1\over n}, 0)$, and the straight line segment from $({1\over n},0)$ to $(1,0)$.

All $f_n$ are continuous, and the sequence converges to $f(x) \equiv 0$
which is also continuous.

But the sequence is not equicontinuous at $x = 0$ because for
$\varepsilon = \frac 12$, arbitrary $\delta > 0$ and all $n > \frac 1\delta$, 
$$
 \bigl | \frac{1}{2n} - 0 \bigr | < \delta \quad\text{ but } \quad 
\bigl| f_n(\frac{1}{2n}) - f_n(0) \bigr| = 1 > \varepsilon \, .
$$

If the limit function is *continuous* and the functions converge
*monotonically* to $f$, then [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) states that the 
convergence is uniform. In that case one can conclude that the
sequence is equicontinuous.

Comment: The example's correct; those functions are not equicontinuous. But the non-equicontinuity does not follow just from the fact that $f_n'(0)\to\infty$. One can have $f_n\to0$ uniformly even though $f_n'$ blows up. (To show your $f_nn$ are not equicontinuous you want to start with " let $\epsilon=1$"...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You are right, I'll fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Typo: You wrote $(0,1/n)$ when you meant $(1/n,0)$. (It was correct the second time this point was used).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I copy/pasted that example from the referenced answer (which is no excuse :). – I hope that all is correct now. Thanks for your feedback and a Happy New Year!