# pointwise convergence to uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am wondering whether the following claim holds or not:

If a sequence of real-valued upper semicontinuous functions is a decreasing sequence and converges to $0$ pointwise, then the convergence is uniform.

This doesn't look true to me, as the answer given  by David Mitra suggests the other way. [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/dinis-theorem-and-tests-for-uniform-convergence#*=*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/dinis-theorem-and-tests-for-uniform-convergence#_=_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is true if the domain is a compact topological space. The proof is the same as for Dini's theorem, since the only property of continuous functions used in the proof is that $\{x:f(x)<\epsilon\}$ is open, which holds also if $f$ is upper semicontinuous.

If the domain is not compact, the result may fail even if the sequence is made up of continuous functions. Consider for instance $f_n(x)=\max(|x|-n,0)$ on $\Bbb R$.